# useCallback with React-Query is executed on every component render

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I've a react app with react-query (tanstack). I created a custom hook that fetches a list of objects from the remote server, and using the `select` option I'm manipulating the data before returning it to the consuming component.

Since the data doesn't change often, I thought using `useMemo` or `useCallback` to memoize the returned data. I've followed the guidelines as [mentioned in the docs](https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-data-transformations#3-using-the-select-option), but my `useCallback` function is executed on every render. I expected it to be triggered only when the data is actually different, is my assumption correct?

I monitor the function execution with the `console.log` line. If I get to see it, I know the func was running. I expected it to be memoized, and not run when the same data is returned from the useQuery, and not seeing the `console.log` line.

```
// hooks.js
export const getData = async (): Promise<DataProps[]> => {
    return await axios.get("/data").then((res) => {
        return res.data
    })
}

export const useDataQuery = () => {
    return useQuery({
        queryKey: ["/data"],
        queryFn: getData,
        select: useCallback((data: DataProps[]): Map<string, DataProps[]> => {
            /* Create a map with dates as keys (YYYY-mm-dd) to array of DataProps */
            const dataMap = new Map<string, dataProps[]>()
            data?.forEach((element) => {
                const dataDate = getDataDate(new Date(element.time))

                if (!dataMap.has(dataDate)) {
                    dataMap.set(dataDate, [])
                }

                const dataOnDate = dataMap.get(dataDate)
                dataMap.push(element)
            })

            console.log("new DataMap")
            return dataMap
        }, []),
    })
}

// component.js
export const ListData = () => {
    const { data: dataMap } = useDataQuery()

    ... component logic ...
```

I also tried adding `staleTime: Infinity`, it didn't change anything.
What am I missing? How can I `useCallback` or `useMemo` here?

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-kalam-yvvqsw

Comment: I would love to run it locally, and check what is happening in there, but I'll try to provide you a quick suggestion.
If I had a similar problem, I would try to keep the hooks under the custom hook context.
So, use the useCallback as a const, and don't return the useQuery, but assign it first in a variable.

Comment: From the documentation I understand that the select is used to transform the data, but the original data are those that are considered stale, and not the transformed ones. The useCallback doesn't help there. Try to get the original data and useMemo outside the component and add the dependencies you need inside that hook.

Comment: That’s a direction I haven’t checked yet. I’ll try that later when I have a chance (both comments). Thank you

Comment: If the intent is to reduce the amount of network requests, the easiest thing to do is probably pass `staleTime: 3*60*1000 // 3 minutes` (or some other amount of time) to the `useQuery` hook.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I tried to set that with infinity, but it still executed the select function

Comment: @thandem Can you give an example for your 2nd suggestion?

Comment: From the provided sandbox example `select` is not run on each render. Could you specify your issue?